# Rails - How to add contacts to SendGrid marketing campaigns via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, sendgrid, rest-client

I need to make HTTP get and post requests with SendGrid to add contacts to our account, however there doesn't seem to be a gem for their email marketing functionality.

It boils down to making a few requests however I can't get past their authentication step.

[They say to do this](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-Single-Recipient-POST)

```
curl -X "GET" "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/templates" -H "Authorization: Bearer Your.API.Key-HERE" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

And using the Rest-Client gem I'm trying to make the authentication request like so...

```
username = 'username'
api_key = 'SG.MY_API_KEY'
key = Base64.encode64(username + ":" + api_key)
headers = {"Authorization" => "Bearer #{key}", "Content-Type" => "application/json"}
response = RestClient.get 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/templates', headers
```

which returns...

```
RestClient::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized: {"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"authorization required"}]}
```

The ultimate objective of [using their API is to add contacts](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-Single-Recipient-POST).

How am I incorrectly making this get request?

Comment: `RestClient.get 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/templates', {:content_type => :json},{ :Authorization => "Bearer #{api_key}"}`

Comment: `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 1..2)`

Comment: Your code looks OK. Have you definitely configured that API key to be authorised to use the necessary APIs in [Sendgrid settings](https://app.sendgrid.com/settings/api_keys)?

Comment: Yes. I also created a new key with access to everything to make sure it wasn't that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. For future reference, here's the code that worked...

```
require 'rest_client'
api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
headers = {'Authorization' => "Bearer #{api_key}"}
data = {:email => 'email@website.com'}
response = RestClient.post 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients', [data].to_json, headers
```

Comment: Thank you this was useful, I think if you would like to add multiple contacts you can have it like this data = [{:email => 'email@website.com'},{:email => 'email2@website.com'}] and remove [] from [data].to_json. So, how can you add them to a specific list

Answer (score 1):

To add marketing contacts to your SendGrid account via the API, 
see the documentation at https://sendgrid.api-docs.io/v3.0/contacts-api-recipients/add-recipients

You can see sample code in the "code generation" section of the page.

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

url = URI("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request["authorization"] = 'Bearer <<YOUR_API_KEY>>'
request["content-type"] = 'application/json'
request.body = "[{\"email\":\"example@example.com\",\"first_name\":\"\",\"last_name\":\"User\",\"age\":25},{\"email\":\"example2@example.com\",\"first_name\":\"Example\",\"last_name\":\"User\",\"age\":25}]"

response = http.request(request)
puts response.read_body
```