# How to automatically add newsletter signups to your contacts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp, sendgrid

After reading the [SendGrid API](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Marketing_Campaigns/contactdb.html#Add-Single-Recipient-POST), **I don't know where to put the code** they provide to actually add the newsletter signups to the online contacts list automatically, instead of manually copying each one from my DB.

> **Add Single Recipient [POST]**
>
> *Request*
>
> `POST https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients HTTP/1.1`
>
> *Request Body*

```
[
  {
    "email": "example@example.com",
    "last_name": "Jones",
     "pet": "Fluffy",
    "age": 25
  }
]
```

I have a Model called `Newsletter` and I am able to get users added to my app's DB and a verification email sent/confirmed via:

```
<%= simple_form_for @newsletter, url: newsWelcome_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: false, placeholder: "First Name", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.input :email, label: false, placeholder: "Email Address", class: "form-control" %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Sign up!", class: "submit btn btn-block btn-info" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the newsletterController:

```
def new
  @newsletter = Newsletter.new
  set_meta_tags noindex: true
end

def create
  @newsletter = Newsletter.new(news_params)
  if @newsletter.save
    @newsletter.send_verification_email
    flash[:info] = "Please check your email for verification, Thanks!"
    redirect_to newsWelcome_path
  else
    flash[:warning] = "Oops! We couldn't send the verifiaction email, please try again!"
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
  end
end

...

private

  def news_params
    params.require(:newsletter).permit(:name, :email)
  end
```

**Do I need to put this in my environment files, newsletterController, Model, or what?**

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513857/rails-how-to-add-contacts-to-sendgrid-marketing-campaigns-via-api) but it still leaves me with the question of where this all goes.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ActiveRecord's [`after_create`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) hook do achieve this. These hooks/callbacks are called on different events. The method you specify in `after_create` will be called when a new record is successfully created.

It can look like this:

```
class Newsletter < ApplicationRecord
  after_create :send_newsletter
  after_create :add_to_sendgrid

  def send_newsletter
    send_verification_email # remove from controller
  end

  def add_to_sendgrid
    # Create the payload and send the request to sendgrid from here
  end
end
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for pointing out that I should move verification to my model. As for the payload, etc. I don't quite understand what you mean by that. I'm not sure how to even format or implement the code from their API. Unless it really is just copy and paste, but I doubt that.

Comment: Will advice you to go through the api examples to know how you can make it work in your use case. Can't help by spoonfeeding the entire answer. First step may be to play with api examples